# Why does ofstream mess up my pointers?

Tags: c++, data-structures, heap

```
void Heap::printHeap(string file) {
  string heapString = "graph {\n";
  for (int i = 1; i < heapSize; i++) {
  Node parentNode = heap[i];
  heapString += parentNode.nodeToDotFormat() + "\n";

  int leftChildIndex = 2 * i;
  int rightChildIndex = 2 * i + 1;
  if (leftChildIndex < heapSize) {
    heapString += parentNode.nodeToDotFormat();
    heapString += "--";

    Node leftChild = heap[leftChildIndex];
    heapString += leftChild.nodeToDotFormat();
    heapString += "\n";

    if (rightChildIndex < heapSize) {
      heapString += parentNode.nodeToDotFormat();
      heapString += "--";

      Node rightChild = heap[rightChildIndex];
      heapString += rightChild.nodeToDotFormat();
      heapString += "\n";
    }
  }
  }
  heapString += "}";
  ofstream out(file);
  out << heapString;
  out.close();
}
```

I'm trying to print my heap. And the heaps consist of struct of Nodes with pointers. For some reason though when the `ofstream` gets executed down below the code it messes up the pointers of my heaps. What could be causing this? And how would I fix it.

This is what the points look like before `ofstream` line is executed:

[image]

This is what it looks like after `ofstream` gets executed:
[image]

As you can see it changed the left child letter and weight, and the right child letter weight. Why do you think ofstream causes this behavior?

Here is the Node struct:

```
struct Node {
char letter;
int weight;
string nodeInString() {
  string nodeString = "{'";
  char copyletter = letter;
  nodeString.append(&copyletter);
  nodeString += "', ";
  nodeString += to_string(weight);
  nodeString += "}";
  return nodeString;
};
string nodeToDotFormat() {
  string dotString = "";
  char copyletter = letter;
  dotString.append(&copyletter);
  dotString += "_";
  dotString += to_string(weight);
  return dotString;
}

Node *leftChild;
Node *rightChild;
};
```

Comment: Sounds like memory corruption of some sort. Have you tried running your program in valgrind?

Comment: Do you have the code to your `nodeToDotFormat` member function?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Your heap is probably full of dangling pointers

Answer (score 3):

The following copy-initializations raise some suspicions

```
Node parentNode = heap[i];
...
Node leftChild = heap[leftChildIndex];
...
Node rightChild = heap[rightChildIndex];
```

It looks like you are *copying* `Node` objects from `heap` array to local variables. If you forgot to follow the Rule-Of-Three (or Rule-of-Five) for class `Node` or implemented the corresponding functions incorrectly, then destructors of the above local objects might also damage or destroy the original objects in `heap` array.

But it is hard to say without seeing your destructors. Show the definition of `Node` and its member functions.

Of course, a big question is *why* are you copying  these nodes into local variables at all? It appears that `printHeap` function should not need to modify the original node data. Hence there should be no need to introduce copies.